# iPhone, How do I force one view into landscape mode?

Tags: iphone

How do I force one view into landscape mode for a graph.

I want to click a tab bar button to make the graph view appear then when a button is clicked on that view I want to push a child screen which I need in portrait mode.

Once they click back i want to return to the graph view in landscape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use UIView's transform property to rotate it by PI radians:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);         
self.view.transform = newTransform;

}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4

Comment: Note that this answer is very old.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```

or

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

Comment: setOrientation is known to be a reason to get app rejected